# Animations are missing in the Tour page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, tour

On the [Stack Exchange Tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour) page, there are some animations for the images, those are pulling from right to left.

**Sample animation:**

> [image: Animation Tour]

But those animations are missing in the other Stack Exchange site's tour pages.
Such as [Stack Overflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [Meta Stack Exchange Tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour), [Database Administrators Tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Wow! This might actually be by design. These tour sites you mentioned at the end are all responsive; they’re newly designed. I can’t confirm that right now, but I think Stack Overflow in dark mode had the [shadow colors wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396704/4642212) all the time before the redesign. I prefer it without these animations, but I’m also not a new contributor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, the animations are gone. I had to remove them because they were calculated with exact pixel values using ancient, rigid JavaScript. The approach to the animation wouldn’t work in a responsive layout, and getting rid of them solved several bugs.

Like a lot of our pages, this one was very old and hadn’t been touched for some years. We couldn’t leave this one alone though, since it’s a lot of user’s first badge.