# When I click the "Tour"-button on English Language Learners-site the right edge of the text is partially cut off

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When I click the "Tour"-button the right edge of the text is partially cut off. I have to guess what's meant there. How can I change this fault if at all?

**If there are animations, where can I find them on the ELL's-site, please? I can't find them actually.**

Comment: Seems to be the case here too https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour . If its by design, it is rather confusing

Comment: No repro, appears fine to me. Screenshot and browser details please? (/cc @Journeyman)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TvA4.png right edge of the examples. I'm running vivaldi, a chrome fork, but reproduced it in chrome

Comment: @JourneymanGeek [Animations are missing in the Tour page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376895/312043) - the same issue you are referring?

Comment: Ah, potentially. In this case though, one can imagine the temporary solution is rather confusing, It could be by design, or something that perhaps should be reviewed in due course

Comment: Well those are just example posts, meant to show the voting arrows, and the general concept, putting whole screenshot will just clog the screen. Animation was nice to have, but without it, guess this is the "least bad" way to show it.

Comment: Depends. If you're a new user and seeing all half cut off examples - its possible you might be confused. OP was! I haven't even seen the tour in years and didn't realise it was intentional.